# How to get user instance in Model Serializer in django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models `CustomUser` and `Student`. In `CustomUserSerializer`, whenever the user is created i also want to create `Student` instance inside `CustomUserSerializer`. How can I get the current user instance?

```py
# models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), unique=True, blank=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

```py
# serializers.py
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomUser
        fields = [
            'id', 'email', 'is_teacher', 'is_student',..]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if validated_data.get('is_student') == True:
             Student.objects.create(user=...?) # what should I put here?

        return super(CustomUserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

**[UPDATED]**
I have another question it's related to `Student` model.
If I have models like below should I create serializer for `Student`? when I want to have serializer for `Class`.

```py
class Class(models.Model):
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your create method as

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        is_student = validated_data.pop("is_student", False)
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        if is_student:
            Student.objects.create(user=user)
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomUser
        fields = [
            'id', 'email', 'is_teacher', 'is_student',..
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have one more question that related to `Student` model. I have just edited the question. Do you mind reading the update part and give me some feed back?

Comment: Actually, it depends on your use-case. That is, how do you plan to connect those entities using the API, how they are getting called from the front-end etc

Comment: This is what i want to do. `Teacher` create the class and the `Class` object will generate random code and `Student` can join the class with that code.